# What are all the finite groups where every nontrivial element has order $3?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I know that the powers of any group where all elements have order $3$ also has this property. I also know that the Heisenberg group has this property and that all finitely generated such groups are finite. What are all the finite groups where every nontrivial element has order $3?$ In particular, what is the order and structure of the free Burnside group $B(m,3)?$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Levi and van der Waerden proved groups of exponent $3$ are nilpotent of class at most $3.$ By work of Levi, they are also $2-$Engel. The complete description appears in Marshall Hall, Jr.'s *The Theory of Groups*, Section 18.2.

The order of $B(3,r)$ (the free Burnside group of exponent $3$ and rank $r$, following the notation of Hall) is $3^{m(r)}$, where $m(r) = r+\binom{r}{2} + \binom{r}{3}$ (Theorem 18.2.1), and every element can be written uniquely as
$$g=x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_r^{a_r}\prod_{1\leq i\lt j\leq r}[x_i,x_j]^{b_{ij}} \prod_{1\leq i\lt j\lt k\leq r}[x_i,x_j,x_k]^{c_{ijk}}$$
with exponents taken modulo $3$, where the $x_i$ are the free generators; the product is given by the standard commutator collection formulas.

Comment: what is that notation in the final product?

Comment: @mathlander What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the one that looks like an associator.

Comment: @mathlander It's a commutator $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$. Basic notion and notation in group theory. Anyone talking about "free Burnside groups" (and hence about varieties of groups) should know what a commutator is already.

Comment: The "commutator" with 3 inputs is what I'm referring to.

Comment: @matlander Also standard notation when working with varieties and nilpotent groups. $[a,b,c]=[[a,b],c]$, when following left-normed convention (which goes with $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$).

Comment: Do infinite groups where every nontrivial element has order 3 also have to be 2-Engel with nilpotency class at most 3?

Comment: @mathlander Both of those conditions are local: if every 2-generated subgroup is 2-Engel, then the group is 2-Engel. A group is nil-3 if the identity $[[[a,b],c],d]=1$ holds, so if it holds in every f.g. subgroup, then it holds in the group. So of course the answer is yes.

Comment: @mathlander And the theorems quoted do not say "finite" anywhere. I am not in the habit of eliding finiteness.